# I am new to cypress+TS. Not able to return a value inside the each loop in Cypress with Typescript

Tags: typescript, cypress, cypress-each

Not able to return a value inside each loop in Cypress with Typescript. `patientBalance` value is undefined.

Main class code

```
let patientBalance: number = getPatientBalance(claimNumber);
```

Function as below:

```
let amountInDollar1: string[];
let amount1: number;
export let getPatientBalance = (claimNumber: string) => {
  getClaimNumberCells().each((input, index) => {
    const claimText = input.text();
    getChargesTable().scrollTo('right');
    if (claimText.includes(claimNumber)) {
      getPatientBalanceCell()
        .eq(index)
        .each((data) => {
          amountInDollar1 = data.text().split('$');
          amount1 = parseFloat(amountInDollar[1]);
          console.log('Amount in loop', +amount1);
        });
    }
  });
  return amount1;
};
```

Also, I want to use this `patientBalance` at multiple points throughout the test. How can I assign this value to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.each()` command is asynchronous, so you can't return synchronously as you have tried to do.

I think adding some `.then()` calls should do what you want to do:

```js
export let getPatientBalance = (claimNumber: string) => {

  getClaimNumberCells().each((input, index) => {
    // calculate
  })

  return cy.then(() => {  // returning the cy.then() ensures async completed

    // option 1 - put value in an alias for multiple use in same test
    cy.wrap(amount1).as('oldPatientBalance')  // an alias stores the value 

    // option 2 - put value in an env variable for use across multiple tests
    Cypress.env('oldPatientBalance', amount1)

    // option 3 - return the value directly 
    return amount1                            // or direct return of value
  })
})

// In test(s) 

// option 3 -  use the returned value
getClaimNumberCells().then(amount1 => {   
  // use it here
})

// option 1 - take the value from the alias later in the same test
cy.get('@oldPatientBalance').then(oldPatientBalance => {
  console.log('oldPatientBalance', oldPatientBalance);
}

// option 2 - should be accessible in other tests (not same test)
it('another test for where amount is calculated', () => {
  const oldPatientBalance = Cypress.env('oldPatientBalance')
})
```

Comment: Actually, I am able to get the value into the test but if I have to use it throughout the test, How can I use it? Because the below line of code is giving an undefined value. 
     let oldPatientBalance: number;
    getPatientBalance(claimNumber).then((patientBalance) => {
      console.log('patientBalance', patientBalance);
      oldPatientBalance = amount;
    });
    cy.then(() => {
      console.log('oldPatientBalance', oldPatientBalance);
    });

Comment: I think you can add an [alias](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as) to get that done. Will add the code above.

Comment: If you want the value across multiple tests, be aware that Cypress clears the aliases between each test to avoid unexpected contamination between tests. In that case, you can set it into an environment variable. Will also add that example above.